# How to remove marker from plot and make it smooth

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, linspace

I have been trying to plot a smooth graph, and here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fig,axes= plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=1, squeeze=False)

x = df["DOY"]
y = df["By"]
z = df["Bz"]
a = df["Vsw"]
b = df["Nsw"]
c = df["magnetopause_distance"]
d = df["reconnection_rate"]
```

And after that, I used the following logic to plot the same

```
#create a figure
fig=plt.figure()

#define subplots and define their position
plt1=fig.add_subplot(611)
plt2=fig.add_subplot(612)
plt3=fig.add_subplot(613)
plt4=fig.add_subplot(614)
plt5=fig.add_subplot(615)
plt6=fig.add_subplot(616)

plt1.plot(x,y,'black',linewidth=0.5,marker=None)
plt1.set_ylabel("By")
plt1.set_title("3-6 July 2003")


plt2.plot(x,z,'black',linewidth=0.5)
plt2.set_ylabel("Bz")

plt3.plot(x,a,'black',linewidth=0.5)
plt3.set_ylabel("Vsw")

plt4.plot(x,b,'black',linewidth=0.5)
plt4.set_ylabel("Nsw")

plt5.plot(x,c,'black',linewidth=0.5)
plt5.set_ylabel("MD")

plt6.plot(x,d,'black',linewidth=0.5)
plt6.set_ylabel("MRR")


plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 2,wspace = 2)



#saving plot in .jpg format
plt.savefig('myplot01.jpg', format='jpeg',dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Finally, I am getting a plot like this:
[image]

What I want is something like this:
[image]

Sorry for the typos. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: seems like a data issue, not a plotting issue

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import numpy as np

list_x_new = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)
list_y_smooth = UnivariateSpline(x, y, list_x_new)

plt.plot(list_x_new, list_y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

This is for one of the graphs, you can substitute the values in `list_y_smooth` in place of `y` according to the values you want to plot.

Comment: getting an error:cannot import name 'spline' from 'scipy.interpolate' (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py)
Thanks for your time

Comment: I just saw that `spline` is now deprecated, I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Can you please elaborate the np.linspace() and its parameters?

Comment: I am getting some errors maybe due to data set limits. Although the code is working.

Comment: Because your data was too packed according to you, so I tried to space out the x-axis values so that the graph smoothens out. You can change the parameters according to your specification, here's the documentation for `linspace()` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: Do consider upvoting and verifying the answer if you found it helpful.